# PHP: transparent area in PNG

Tags: php, gd

I want to create a transparent area in a png image, some sort of "hole". So I could place this image on top of some background image and see a fragment of the background through that "hole". I found this code on some forum:

```
$imgPath = 'before.png';
$img = imagecreatefrompng($imgPath); // load the image
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($imgPath); // get its size
$c = imagecolortransparent($img,imagecolorallocate($img,255,1,254)); // create transparent color, (255,1,254) is a color that won't likely occur in your image
$border = 10;
imagefilledrectangle($img, $border, $border, $width-$border, $height-$border, $c); // draw transparent box
imagepng($img,'after.png'); // save
```

It works for creating the transparent area (rectangular in this case) in png image. But when I place this png image on top of other image, the area loses transparency, so I end up with the colored rectangle in the middle of the resulting image. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You mean that the image you obtain has the transparent hole? If yes, than maybe is a browser's fault..which one are you using?

Comment: No, I mean that the image I obtain contains rgb(255,1,254) filled rectangle instead of transparent rectangular area. Anyway, I've just found the answer to this issue. I was using imagecopy() for copying the png onto a background. And transparency is copied only with imagecopymerge(). Should have read the documentation more carefully.

Comment: Good! Have fun with the transparencies :D

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option would be using the PHP ImageMagick extension, [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

You can create the rectangle by setting the background parameter of the [Imagick::newImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.newimage.php) function, the cicle using the [ImagickDraw::circle](http://php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.circle.php) function, and the key is to apply the circle using the [Imagick::compositeImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php) and [only copying the transparency](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.constants.php#imagick.constants.composite-copyopacity) over. This will prevent you from having a solid image with a transparent circle on top; everything that is transparent in the mask will be transparent on the original image.

The below code should do the trick (although I am sure it will need a few tweaks to meet your needs :P):

```
<?php

    $base = new Imagick("before.png");
    $base->cropImage(512, 512, 0, 0);
    $base->setImageMatte(true);

    $mask = new Imagick();
    $mask->newImage(512, 512, new ImagickPixel("transparent"));

    $circle = new ImagickDraw();
    $circle->setFillColor("black");
    $circle->circle(150, 150, 100, 100);

    $mask->drawImage($circle);

    $base->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);

    $base->writeImage('after.png');
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    echo $base;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I've already found the answer for my question, but I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @palehorse, I happen to a same question, could you tell me of your answer? ImageickDraw will be the last way I want to try.

Comment: @anna, you should use the code from the original post to create the "mask" (image with transparent area). Maybe use some other function instead of imagefilledrectangle() depending on your needs. Then you should use imagecopymerge() (not imagecopy()) to copy the "mask" onto the background image. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the transparent colour:

```
$c = imagecolorallocatealpha($img,0,0,0,127);
```